# How to get data from one component to another using Async and await

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have 2 components and 1 service file
                **Component ** is where i need the response
                I'm trying to call the the function which is present in the Master component from Component 1 and i'm getting the response from the service back to Master component.

I'm worried how do i get the same API response to be transferred from Master component to Component 1 By using Async and await...Please Help Me..:

**Component .ts**

```
        async data( ){
            const same= await this.Mastercomponent.function();
            console.log(same, ": function result");
```

**Mastercomponent.ts**

```
        async function( ) {
        this.service._getdata(ob).subscribe(
              data => { 
         console.log(data, "Response Recieved in Mastercomponent");
         return data;
        })}
```

**Service.ts**

```
         return this.http.post(param, { headers: head, responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
              tap(data => {
                console.log(data, "Response Recieved in Service");
              }),
              catchError(this.getError)
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions return promises, but your master component function does not have any explicit `return` statement, so it promises `undefined`. The only one `return` occurs in a callback which is irrelevant for the `async` function's return value.

There are several solutions to make this function work, so this is just one of them:

```
function( ) {
    return this.service._getdata(ob).toPromise().then(data => {
//  ^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        console.log(data, "Response Recieved in Mastercomponent");
        return data;
    });
}
```

Note that you actually don't need the `async` keyword here, because now you already return a promise, and don't use `await`. As a general rule, functions that don't have `await`, don't need to have the `async` keyword (although it doesn't break the code if you include it).

Comment: Awesome Sir, i was Struggling for this from 2 Weeks and was using as setting data in the service and making as Observable but i know that was not a right way. Thank you so much sir.